# How can I query related tags from a relationship table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb, subquery

I can't find an answer to my problem on the site.

I have 3 tables: data, tags and data_tag_rel.

**data**

```
id     data
------------------------------------
1      A string of long data A.
2      A string of long data B.
3      A string of long data C.
4      A string of long data D.
5      A string of long data E.
6      A string of long data F.
7      A string of long data G.
8      A string of long data H.
n      Etc...
```

**tags**

```
id     tag
------------
1      gold
2      silver
3      copper
4      emerald
5      steel
6      ruby
7      carbon
8      zinc
9      mercury
n      Etc...
```

**data_tag_rel**

```
data     tag
------------------
1        1
1        2
2        1
3        2
4        3
5        1
5        2
5        3
6        1
7        1
8        1
8        2
8        4
8        6
n        n
```

As you can see, there is data and tags, and a relationship table to determine what tags are assigned to what data. Here the data is talking about minerals and rocks.

**The query I want** is to SELECT the tags (id and name) that are related to a set of more tags in the relationship table, by looking at what data id they target in common.

So for example, imagine I assign a data id 8 to be related to tags 1:"gold", 2:"silver", 4:"ruby" and 6:"emerald" in the relationship table. So now I would like to query common tags. If I query "gold", "silver", I would like to get returned either:

A. "gold", "silver", "ruby" and "emerald" (include the search tags).
or
B. "ruby" and "emerald" (don't include the search tags).

The purpose is to click a tag and see what other tags are related to that clicked tag,by what data they are related to in common, using the relationship table as a guide.

So far I managed to make it work searching for only 1 tag, but I can't make it work for 2, 3 or n tags.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tags.tag FROM tags, data_tag_rel WHERE tags.id = data_tag_rel.tag AND data_tag_rel.data IN (SELECT data_tag_rel.data FROM data_tag_rel WHERE data_tag_rel.tag IN (SELECT tags.id FROM tags WHERE tags.tag IN ('gold')));
```

How can I query related tags to a list of 2 or more tags in this database structure?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  data_tag_rel.data
FROM
  data_tag_rel
WHERE
  data_tag_rel.tag IN ((SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tags.tag IN ('silver', 'gold')))
GROUP BY
  data_tag_rel.data
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 2
```

If it's possible for a data item to have the same tag multiple times, that changes slightly...

```
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT data_tag_rel.tag) = 2
```

The nasty nested `IN()` can also be replaced if you feel like it...

```
FROM
  data_tag_rel
INNER JOIN
  tags
    ON tags.id = data_tag_rel.tag
WHERE
  tags.tag IN ('silver', 'gold')
```

The crux of it is; filter normally, then use the `HAVING` clause to make sure you have two mathces, not just one.

***EDIT:***

To be explicit about how to get from there to the associated tags, just join back on to the `data_tag_rel` table...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  tags.tag
FROM
(
  SELECT
    data_tag_rel.data  AS id
  FROM
    data_tag_rel
  WHERE
    data_tag_rel.tag IN ((SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tags.tag IN ('silver', 'gold')))
  GROUP BY
    data_tag_rel.data
  HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 2
)
  AS data
INNER JOIN
  data_tag_rel
    ON data_tag_rel.data = data.id
INNER JOIN
  tags
    ON tags.id = data_tag_rel.tag
```

Comment: @kintsukuroi - You just join back on to the `data_tag_rel` table...  *(Answer updated)*

Comment: This last edit works! Thank you so much Mat :D may God bless you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic you want is:

```
select t.*
from tags t
where exists (
    select 1
    from data_tag_rel dtr
    inner join data_tag_rel dtr1 on dtr1.data = dtr.data
    inner join tags t1 on t1.id = dtr1.tag
    where t1.tag in ('gold', 'silver') and dtr.tag = t.id
)
```

Comment: Ok, so this is near to what I need but not exactly. This returns all tags SUM related to gold and silver, but not INTERSECT related to gold and silver. In other words, this code is getting what is related to gold, then what is related to silver, then joining those 2 together in a large set. What I need is the tags that are only related to both, not the separate SUM of both. Do you see this subtle difference? Really appreciate the help! Thanks :D

Comment: Since this works for other use cases and might help others, I'll vote it up too, thanks!